# Find duplicate char and count it

Tags: python, count, duplicates

Is there a way to count duplicate + count from a list itself? For example:

```
list01= ['','home','welcome', 'to', 'my','happy', 'birthday']

  for i in list01:
       for char in i :
            count = 0
            if char = char;
                count = +1
                print (count, char)
```

I want to get the number of times a char is present in the whole list.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you even tried to run this. There is a syntax error in your `if statement`.

Comment: Try use `if char == char:` instead `if char = char;`.

Comment: `char == char` is always `True`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to write it from scratch, you can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to achieve this very easily.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

list01= ['','home','welcome', 'to', 'my','happy', 'birthday']
print Counter(chain(*list01))

# or alternatively, as noted by Peter Wood
print Counter(chain.from_iterable(list01))
```

To do the equivalent, with just using the built-ins, you can use a dictionary to keep track of the unique keys (the characters) and add to it's counter.

```
list01= ['','home','welcome', 'to', 'my','happy', 'birthday']
counter = {}
for element in list01:
    for character in element:
        if character in counter:
            counter[character] += 1
        else:
            counter[character] = 1
```

Comment: [**`chain.from_iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) avoids the `*`.

Comment: Just to be clear: `''.join(chain.from_iterable(list01)) == 'homewelcometomyhappybirthday'`

Comment: You don't need to join the output from `chain` as Counter accepts any iterable, and the result from chain is generator for a list, and lists and strings are iterable all the same.

Comment: I'm illustrating the effect of the chain, in case it wasn't clear, that you get a single sequence. I thought saying `list(chain.from_iterable(list01)) == ['h', 'o', 'm', ...]` would be less clear. Maybe not!

Comment: Hello,

Thanks a lot for your answers.

I would like to write it from scratch.

Next try was this one still not working great. 
--
list01= ['','home','welcome', 'to', 'my','happy', 'birthday']

for i in list01:
    for char in i :
        count = 0
        print 
        if char == char:
            count = +1
            print (count, char)
---

I keep trying and I get back to let you guys know how did it work.

Best Regards.

Comment: I edited the post to include an equivalent version that just uses the built-ins for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys I found the way to do it see the answer below.

```
list01= ['','home','welcome', 'to', 'my','happy', 'birthday']
str = "".join(list01)
count = 0
char = "h"
for i in str:
    if i == char :
        count +=1
        total =count
print total, char
```

I got 3h when I run it.

Have a nice day and enjoy your every moment with python.

Thanks a lots for your time.

Best regards,